# again about appendix to make hidden slides

Tags: beamer, hyperref, conditionals

I tried to put some slides in the appendix, but it doesn't work on my compiler. If I add an appendix after the first compilation it works, probably because the navigation bar is not yet updated, but after a second compilation the appendix slides are shown in the navigation bar. Usually it is necessary to compile at least twice for updating crossreferences for example. Furthermore, if I use slide show mode of the Apple Preview application all slides, including the ones in the appendix, are shown in any case. Could you please help also me?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\title{The Title} \author{The Author} \date{\today} 
\begin{document} 
\section{One} 
\begin{frame}[label=main] 
I suspect someone might ask about supplemental material \hyperlink{supplemental}{\beamerbutton{here}}. 
\end{frame} 
\appendix 
\section{More} 
\begin{frame}[label=supplemental] 
Supplemental content. Back to \hyperlink{main}{\beamerbutton{main}}. 
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! This [comment by samcarter on the last beamer question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/483045/adjusting-a-logo-position-and-size-in-the-fibeamer-theme#comment1221142_483045) applies here, too: It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) (MWE) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: hello I am Enrico Filippi, I asked the question with title: again about appendix to make hidden slides.      I used a latex source posted in this website, I wrote in another comment because it is too long

Comment: \documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\title{The Title}
\author{The Author}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\section{One}
\begin{frame}[label=main]
I suspect someone might ask about supplemental material
\hyperlink{supplemental}{\beamerbutton{here}}.
\end{frame}
\appendix
\section{More}
\begin{frame}[label=supplemental]
Supplemental content.
Back to \hyperlink{main}{\beamerbutton{main}}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Comment: Please add the code to your question.

Comment: @EnricoFilippi The code from your comment works fine for me. Can you please elaborate what "doesn't work" means? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @samcarter I did not get error messages, just few warnings but they seen not related.   By the beamer manual I understood that if you put some slides in the appendix they will not be shown in the navigation bar, namely by clicking the right arrow navogation bar it will be not possible to reach the appendix slides. Howevere after compiling twice this code I am able to reach the appendix slides by the navigation bar. What about you? Did you try to compile twice that code? If so, if you click on right arrow navigation bar can you reach all slides?

Comment: @EnricoFilippi The slides in appendix will be excluded from the section navigation in the headline. This is unrelated from the navigation symbols at the bottom right, they will still be able to reach the appendix.

Comment: @samcarter ok, so what does it mean that they will be exluded from from the section navigation in the headline?  Are there no chances to exclude from presentation some slides, but to show them by using hyperlink?